# Question about pausing journeys

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Hello I found [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_pause.htm&type=5) but was a little confused cause it says " Contacts processed by Journey Builder and queued for sending aren’t paused."

I have a journey with a wait that will be going out on Monday and they want to delay it.

There are currently 250 contacts in the wait.

-So if I pause this journey will the contacts under the "WAIT" still be sent the last email even if it is paused?

-I can pause the journey and change the date to later with no issues right?  Currently I cannot change the time because it is active

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This line "Contacts processed by Journey Builder and queued for sending aren’t paused." means contacts that have reached the email activity and possibly in the queue for the triggeredsend will still be sent to.

Unless you are using send throttling, and large sends with some complex ampscript I wouldn't imagine you would have subscribers in the queue for very long.

BUT you could be in a situation that some emails go out after you pause the journey